# Exoplayer library version conflicts

Tags: java, android

Currently, I'm using exoplayer library with version 2.3.1. I want to include exoplayer version 2.7.0 in the same project how can we do that without conflict? If anyone has the answer most welcome but please don't close my issue because the organization I work for theme , they have different vendors so their requirement is for different versions so I can't tell the reason why I want to do that.

for more info https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3988

Comment: why you required that? Just use v2.7.0

Comment: I am using third party sdk for play some particular video files they are using 2.3.1 as well as i want to play my local contents with latest exo player version 2.7.0.

Comment: Which SDK??? I have a workaround for that.. just override their dependency. If you still face some issue then download their code you need to update there sdk.

Comment: hungama sdk version 2.3.1 . if u have worked on exoplayer can you suggest how can i include 2.7.0 as well as 2.3.1 both because this is my requirement now.

Comment: I have also faced this issue. So in the end, I found that it is not possible to integrate them both. So, I had to upgrade my complete app along with the SDK

Comment: but i was using version 1.5.12 and 2.3.1 simultaneously and it was working fine.i was keeping the libraries along with the different packages.

Comment: for v1 and v2 someone has made libraries on git so i was taking his packages but now for v2 ,v2  i m not sure anyone has made or not.

Comment: You are able to do so because both have a different package name.

Comment: and you also make the app unnecessarily heavy, don't you think so?

Comment: hungama?? can you provide me the link of this SDK

Comment: any way i have to do it like that way . I have no other option

Comment: sdk having exoplayer 2.3.1 libraries nothing else . you can see exoplayer 2.3.1 lib in git

Comment: if you own the sdk then upgrade the exoplayer version there

Comment: i cant edit it its third party sdk

Comment: which functionality of 2.7.0 you want

Comment: not a single one so i will tell manually

Comment: you are working on Music player type app right?

Comment: basically on video player i am working

Comment: don't use exoplayer then, not able to many format and decoding is also not good

Comment: its already implemented i am just upgrading it

Comment: can you post the error/conflict

Comment: 03-15 12:17:10.490 2474-2474/com.ideacellular.digitalvideo E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method addListener(Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer$EventListener;)V in class Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer' appears in /data/app/com.ideacellular.digitalvideo-2/base.apk:classes10.dex)

Comment: i can tell you the work around.. but that very bad approach

Comment: ok you can suggest

Comment: add exoplayer 2.7.0 as module in your app.. change its package name. and enjoy. 100% working

Comment: that is my question how to change package name ?

Comment: exo player libraries have package name provided by google i cant change it. if you have suggesion please provide it .

Comment: you know how to use lib as module?

Comment: No I don't .can you tell me the process how to do it because I am a fresher so haven't done that yet.

Comment: https://mayojava.github.io/android/library/creating-and-distributing-your-own-android-library/

Comment: is this the process?

Comment: https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio

Comment: wt is this link?

Comment: i am not getting the solution can you explain me a little ?

Comment: #download the source code from github. #File> Import Module> define the path

Comment: I downloaded the demo app for exoplayer from github.

Comment: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/library/all import this in your project

Comment: Error:Could not read script '/Users/Vinod/Documents/Office Project Pallavi/constants.gradle' as it does not exist.

I m getting this error while importing module.

Comment: /constants.gradle' as it does not exist ? should i add some path in my gradle?

Comment: No. You haven't imported the module in a right way.

Comment: ok let me try to fix it in right way if i will be needing help i will ask you.

Comment: see the constant.grade file is in under exoplayer folder but i have imported library folder which is dependent on constant. gradle dats why its throwing error

Comment: let me try on my system

Comment: Are you using only core or all functionality like UI also?

Comment: that i dnt know now i think all

Comment: are you creating your UI by own?

Comment: yes we already created ui .

Comment: ok what is dash and hls  i will be needing that also?

Comment: no need, try with only core first

Comment: ok trying with core first.

Answer (score 1):

copy /constants.gradle to your project : 
and replace your build.gradle data with this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: '../constants.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion project.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion project.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion project.ext.targetSdkVersion
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }

    // Workaround to prevent circular dependency on project :testutils.
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs += "../../testutils/src/main/java/"
        }
        test {
            java.srcDirs += "../../testutils/src/main/java/"
            java.srcDirs += "../../testutils_robolectric/src/main/java/"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        // Re-enable test coverage when the following issue is fixed:
        // https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37019591
        // debug {
        //    testCoverageEnabled = true
        // }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:' + supportLibraryVersion
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:' + dexmakerVersion
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:' + dexmakerVersion
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:' + truthVersion
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:' + mockitoVersion
    testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:' + truthVersion
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:' + junitVersion
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:' + mockitoVersion
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:' + robolectricVersion
}

ext {
    javadocTitle = 'Core module'
}

ext {
    releaseArtifact = 'exoplayer-core'
    releaseDescription = 'The ExoPlayer library core module.'
}
```

Comment: this is only for core

Comment: No, this is core.gradle

Comment: copy /constants.gradle to your project . i am not able to do that its not copying for me .

Comment: no error but i copied and pasted in android studio. no errr but the file not copied

Comment: you need to copy at root folder of your project. (C:/ProjectName/here)

Comment: Error:Project with path ':library-core' could not be found in project ':exo-2'.

Comment: again some issue while importing

Comment: Error:Could not find method api() for arguments [project ':library-core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: need to check each step while importing.

Comment: the same process I did on my machine and is working perfectly fine. without seeing the code i think is difficult to find the bug

Comment: i followed this way-- file> new> import module . and i imported library module

Comment: yeah can you tell how will i keep my package different for exoplayer version 2.7.1 if you have easy way  please let me know.

Comment: have you added the module to the app?

Comment: what the exact issue now?

Comment: actually updated player working now but the old sdk with version 2.3.1 is crashing so i want to make both work. and one more issue in defaultbandwidth meter no bandwidth is comming but the bandwidth is there in url.

Comment: bitrate estimate value is -1 can you tell how to make it to initialise the initial bitrate?

Comment: can you post the image of your project structure

Comment: ok i will give can you tell me how to get bandwidth because i have check edfrom demo and i have done like that for me no bandwidth

Comment: bandwidth for what?

Comment: for url videoquality

Comment: MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metaRetriever.setDataSource(/* file descriptor or file path goes here */);
String height = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
String width = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);

Comment: (/* file descriptor or file path goes here */ )what path i should give here ?? and will it work for version 2.7.1?

Comment: add url or Url.parse("URL")

Comment: from where you are playing the videos because its not mandatory that video contains metadata for video quality and subtitles